# Create a nested Bootstrap dropdown toggle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

This is my first question to StackOverflow, so I'm sorry if it's a little wonky.

Anyway, I have a need to use a "back" or "close" link within a Bootstrap dropdown menu. It appears that the dropdown() function only appends the "open" class to the direct parent of the element with the "dropdown-toggle" class.

Anyone have any ideas? Here is my markup:

```
<li class="navbar__nav-item navbar__nav-dropdown dropdown">
<a class="navbar__nav-link navbar__dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">News &amp; Events</a>

<ul class="navbar__nav-dropdown-menu dropdown-menu">
    <li class="navbar__header-menu-title">
        <h6 class="navbar__header-menu-back ">
            <a class="navbar__header-menu-back-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">< Back</a>
        </h6>
        <h6 class="navbar__menu-title">
            Title
        </h6>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__dropdown-menu-item">
        <a class="navbar__dropdown-menu-link" href="component-library.html">Link1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__dropdown-menu-item">
        <a class="navbar__dropdown-menu-link">Link2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what version of Bootstrap and also do you have the .js files linked at the bottom of the page before the closing </body>

Comment: I'm using 3.3.7, and yes, i have linked dropdown.js at the bottom of the page

Comment: can you post ALL your code on https://codepen.io/# or on https://jsfiddle.net/ then link to that in your reply